# Different synchronization types

Tags: synchronization, nodes

What are the different synchronization types for an Ethereum node? Which of them are client-specific (Geth, Parity)?

Comment: This is pretty good :-) -> https://dev.to/5chdn/ethereum-node-configuration-modes-cheat-sheet-25l8

Answer (score 1):

Here are the different node sync options (mostly from @Richard's link https://dev.to/5chdn/ethereum-node-configuration-modes-cheat-sheet-25l8):

**Light**

Synchronizes block headers with a specific protocol, starting from a trusted checkpoint. Supported by both Geth and Parity.

Parity has also a special light sync to do the same light synchronization but starting from the genesis block (block number 0).

**Full**

This is the default sync mode for nodes so it's most likely supported by all clients (existing and future ones). Verifies all blocks and executes all transactions.

Geth uses a *fast* synchronization by default for this which doesn't execute all transactions. Once it reaches the current block it continues with a normal full sync.

Parity uses very similar methods to Geth but its *fast* sync is called *warp* sync (it has some minor differences).

**Archive**

Similar to a *full* sync but stores all intermediate states in disk. Takes about ten times more space than a *full* sync. It seems there are little uses for this synchronization method and almost nobody does it (https://blog.blockcypher.com/ethereum-woes-d9b2af62da67).

Geth and Parity both have this feature; it's called *gcmode* in Geth and *pruning* in Parity.